# Android Run Java every time page accessed

Tags: java, android

I currently have a home screen of my app where it displays a number all this shows is how many questions have been answered. Another button takes you to answer questions and it updates the database value.

I have found that the home page number display only updates the first time the app is opened. If you go back a page it does not update the value.

What should I do to make sure this is run everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe putting your method call in the onResume() method of the main Activity will have it run every time it's re-displayed to the user.